Median regression
I am trying to understand the reason I'm having different results estimating median values with R median and rq (quantreg) functions.
Here is an example of what is confusing me:
PC <- gl(3, 10, labels = LETTERS[1:3])

PU <- c(rlnorm(10, meanlog = 8, sdlog = 1),
        rlnorm(10, meanlog = 9, sdlog = 1),
        rlnorm(10, meanlog = 10, sdlog = 1))

df <- data.frame(PU, PC)

tapply(df$PU, df$PC, mean)
tapply(df$PU, df$PC, median)

LinFit <- lm(PU~PC-1, data = df)
summary(LinFit) # Coefs are the same as obtained tapply(df$PU, df$PC, mean)

rqFit <- rq(PU~PC-1, tau = .5, data = df)
summary(rqFit) # Coefs not the same of medians estimated with tapply(df$PU, df$PC, median)
```


You are ignoring a clear warning issued by the software ("Solution may be nonunique.") To understand it better, change all occurrences of "10" to a small odd number and try again.
